# Incorrect image paths for doxygen

Tags: doxygen

tl;dr question:

What is the *actual* algorithm doxygen uses to find images referenced to in doxygen comments?  And the corollary, what's considered best practice which won't break in future doxygen versions?

Details:

We're trying to institute a policy where any images associated with doxygen comments should be localized to the reference, which means we'll have images distributed throughout the source tree. Obviously, we need to make sure that we refer to the images appropriately and that doxygen can find them to produce the correct documentation.

The [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage) states:

> doxygen will look for files in the paths (or files) that you specified after the IMAGE_PATH tag

However, in my tinkering I've come to the conclusion that this doesn't seem strictly correct.  Here are some experimental results:

================================================

Experiment

File system configuration:

```
/full/
   path/
      doxygen.cfg
      to/
         this/
            header.h
            images/
               image.png
      other/
         images/
            image.png
```

The doxygen config file is in the "root" of the tree (i.e., `/full/path/`) and doxygen is executed from this same folder.`header.h` references `images/image.png` located in the same tree (`/full/path/to/this`).  There is an identically named image file located elsewhere in the tree.  `header.h` has the line:

```
@file html [filename]
```

reference where `[filename]` is one of the following:

1. `image.png`
2. `images/image.png`
3. `./images/image.png`
4. `/full/path/to/this/images/image.png`

Then I play with the `IMAGE_PATH` variable.

Case 1:`IMAGE_PATH =`  (i.e., no path defined).

1. "Wrong" image loaded (other/iamges/image.png)
2. no image
3. no image
4. Correct image loaded

Case 2: `IMAGE_PATH = /full/path` (path provided to root, but not full path to header file).

1. Correct image loaded
2. Correct image loaded
3. Correct image loaded
4. Correct image loaded

Case 3: `IMAGE_PATH = /full/path/other` (path provided to root which does *not* include the header file).

1. "Wrong" image loaded (other/iamges/image.png)
2. "Wrong" image loaded (other/iamges/image.png)
3. "Wrong" image loaded (other/iamges/image.png)
4. Correct image loaded

================================================

Inferred Algorithm Properties

1. Relative paths only work if the relative path is in the tree rooted in a path specified in `IMAGE_PATH`.
2. In the case where the image file name can resolve into different images, doxygen appears to pick the one "closest" to the reference.

Comment: When you say `IMAGE_PATH = /full/path`, is that the full path from the root of the filesystem? Typically I have `doxygen.conf` somewhere in my project and want to give paths relative to the root of the project, and I don't want to worry about where the project is checked out (e.g., in `C:\Foo\Bar\MyProjectCheckout\configs\doxygen.conf`.

Answer (score 5):

First thing first... thanks for posting this, I was starting to think I was missing something obvious. Now I know there are at least two of us...

I was attempting to include a picture in a markdown file; this may explain the slightly different results I got. Also, I tested with \image command only. At first I only got a long series of "image not found" warnings, but eventually I reached some consistent positive results suggesting that:

1. The image is only found when IMAGE_PATH setting points **directly** to the folder where the image is (no parent folder). The manual slightly hints towards this by suggesting that IMAGE_PATH may ba a collection of paths **or files**
2. IMAGE_PATH can be expressed as a full path **or** relative to the location where DOXYGEN is run
3. Moreover, in order for the image to be "found", the file name and path should match **a part of** the actual full name and path of the image

For instance, given a markdown page and an image in the following folders:

```
/some-path/work/my-page.md
/some-path/work/images/some/more/folders/the-image.png
```

In order to copy the page while running DOXYGEN in the "work" folder, IMAGE_PATH should be set as one of the following:

- /some-path/work/images/some/more/folders/the-image.png
- /some-path/work/images/some/more/folders
- images/some/more/folders/the-image.png
- images/some/more/folders

In **all** cases, the image can be successfully referenced in the markdown page as either "the-image.png" or "folders/the-image.png", "more/folders/the-image.png" etc. The criteria is the reference matching part of the actual file path and name (while one could expect the image reference to be relative to the markdown file it appears in - this seems wrong).

I say again, these tests were conducted using a markdown file, and it's possible in this case the mechanics be different from the one applicable to images referenced in source files.

Answer (score 0):

In html documentation, images were replaced with the broken image icon.
After two days of trial and error, I found out that the reason was in the set text direction (Project->**OUTPUT_TEXT_DIRECTION**), it should be **None**, not LTR. The documentation was carried out in two ways:

```
![picture](my_picture.png)

@image html my_picture.png
```

Comment: I don't see what you want to say with your "answer" what problem did you have? Which doxygen version did you use? The default `OUTPUT_TEXT_DIRECTION` is `None`. Furthermore the sysntax of the `@image` command as used here is wrong, it should be `@image html my_picture.png`. Maybe you are after a completely different problem and should submit an other question for it or create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new

Comment: The reason for your skepticism is not very clear. I decided to post my advice here for the reason that while I was dealing with the problem of displaying images in the documentation generated by Doxygen, this page was constantly present in the search results and I hope it will help someone to solve this issue. I don't see the point in creating a question on github, because this is not a bug. Doxygen Version 1.8.17. For the second version of the image insertion syntax, see section 5.1.11 of the Doxgen documentation. With best wishes.

Comment: In section 5.1.11 of the documentation I don't seen anything about `@image` / `\image` command only about the first version in your answer, the used syntax for the `@image`  command is wrong (see documentation paragraph 24.166). Regarding the "this is not  a bug", here we differ in our opinions, it is a bug as in the name attribute of the resulting html image command the code `&#202A;` appeared, for this there is now already a proposed patch (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7690).

Comment: With respect to \image, I agree that I initially misunderstood you and corrected you in the text. With regard to the bug direction of the text, I also agree.

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head on this for hours!

Eventually, I worked out that rather than setting env variables you need to use the doxywizard gui.  Find the Expert tab and then locate the IMAGE_PATH section.  Add your root image path to that.  For me. that got it working, my image root was within my doxygen execution path so that may have helped.  Good luck to others who spend 6 hours trying to make env variables work before they come to this set of posts!!